# Field "Direct Session" im Interface - NOT in Api?

Tags: google-analytics-api

The Interface of Google Analytics 360 offers a field called "Direct Session" (see screenshot).
[image]

Searching Google developer's Dimensions & Metrics guide we cannot find the respective field (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Is it available in the Google Api for Google Analytics 360? If yes, how is it called?

If not available: what is the planned timing for implementation?
Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know this is not accessible through the API. This issue has been raised - you can track the issue here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65659905

Comment: Thanks! Will follow the link.